# ng-model with isolated scope directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an isolated directive as an element

How can I bind the `ngmodel` of it since the return html is being overrided ?

```
&lt;div ng-repeat="x in list"&gt;
    &lt;form-element ng-model="value[x.name]"&gt;&lt;/form-element&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
```

I am having troubles adding the ngmodel to it

**JS :**

```
app.directive('formElement', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope   : {
            type : '=' 
            } ,
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(function () {                      
                        return scope.type ;
                }, function() {
                    var templates           = {};

                    templates['text']       = '&lt;input type ="text" name="{{name}}"&gt;' ;
                    templates['radio']      = '&lt;input ng-repeat="option in optionsList" name="{{name}}" type="radio"&gt;';


                    if (templates[inputType]) {
                        scope.optionsList   = scope.type.data;
                        scope.name          = scope.type.name;

                        element.html(templates[scope.type.inputType]);
                    } else {
                        element.html("");
                    }
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                }

                );  
            }   
        } 
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you update a question with more information please..

Comment: could you please provide the related code too.. the js code.

Comment: added more info @pankajparkar

Comment: @sisimh still not getting your question..could you add more explaination..from where the `type` come & `ng-model` value?

Comment: ok the type is an object where i tell what is the type of html element i want to return ,, so this object will have all the html DOM element attributes that i need ,,, including the inputType lets say radio ,, the html DOM name , value ... everything ... so the return of this directive will be <input type="radio" name="radioname"> ... and so on @pankajparkar .. my question is for the ngmodel . I want to add ngmodel so that on submit i can get that binded value and send it to server after doing the validations

Comment: @sisimh one more question..why you putted watch on `type` any specific reason?

Comment: @pankajparkar well yes actually these inputs are being drawn based on the selected value of a selection list , so lets say i selected A , the drawn element must be text , B will draw radio buttons .. so on .. makes sense ?

Comment: @sisimh make sense..so then the `value` will only contain `ng-model` name which needs to be supplied or `ng-model` with its current value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79214/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-sisimh).

Comment: @pankajparkar feel free to change the logic of the ng-model ,, i was just trying to keep track of the inserted value by the user ,, I also had an idea of making the value as part of the x object , maybe that makes it much cleaner code . so it will become ng-model="x.value" what do u think ?

Comment: @sisimh  yes that would be more cleaner..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want the `ng-model` to introduced inside the field created by the directive you could inject that `ngModel` inside isolated scope.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="x in list">
    <form-element ng-model="x.value" type="x.inputType"></form-element>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('formElement', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      type: '=',
      ngModel: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var templates = {};
        templates['text'] = '<input type ="text" name="{{name}}" ng-model="ngModel">';
        templates['radio'] = '<input ng-repeat="option in optionsList" name="{{name}}" type="radio">';
        if (templates[scope.type]) {
          scope.optionsList = scope.type.data;
          scope.name = scope.type.name;
          element.append($compile(templates[scope.type])(scope));
        } else {
          element.html("");
        }
        //$compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }
  }
});
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/v8PecswRlBdpPmS0DFRf?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much @pankajparker ! very useful discussion :)

Comment: @sisimh Hlad to help you..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is to call a property of your isolated scope "ngModel", but you are not using the ngModelController. This doesn't mean that you are  using the ngModel directive provided by Angular.

You can change the name of your ngModel property in any other name on your directive, and it should works fine.

Using ngModel it means that you add the require:'ngModel'" prop. in your directive object.

```
 return {
  restrict: 'E',
  require:'ngModel',
  scope: {
    type: '='
  }
```

and in the link function use the ngModelController to access to the $viewValue

```
function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtr)
{
  var mymodel=ngModelCtr.$viewValue;
}
```

Here more info.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController